# JSoup gives blank output despite using text() method

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I try to print a div class text(div.rating) in java by using Jsoup, supposed that if the element is null then will print returns empty but it keeps giving me blank output even though I filtered with ifelse statement and printed with text() method. This is the html code.

```
    <div class="team-profile-side-box">
     <div class="header-container">
      <div class="logo-container">
       <div class="team-logo">...</div>
        <div class="rating-wrapper">
         <div class="rating-title">...</div>
          <div class="rating">7.04</div>
        </div>
```

This is my java code and the website that I'm testing is https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/30/Show/England-Tottenham and the element I'm trying to obtain is the team score located on the right side team profile box.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/" + clubID + "/Show/" + clubName + "").get();

    Elements printNumber = doc.select("div.rating-wrapper > div.rating");

    if (printNumber != null && !printNumber.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(printNumber.text());
    } else if (printNumber == null && printNumber.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("returns empty");
    }
```

Please help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the website is protected by Incapsula, therefore there is no way to access the page's html by using JSoup.